# How can I keep the output of a model over the testing data during training, in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Keras calculates the output of a model on the testing data at the end of each batch to calculate metrics like validation loss, validation acc, and so on. Is there a way to access the output of the model on the entire dataset that Keras is calculating?

I know that I can calculate it with a callback function that uses *model.predict* and *on_epoch_end* to stack all the predictions in a single array, but that would involve evaluating the testing dataset *twice* for each epoch.

Is there a way to access all the predictions of the model on the testing data?